# Predict/impute one cell of matrix using all other cells

Tags: pca, predictive-models, missing-data, data-imputation, correspondence-analysis

**The question**: I want to predict/impute one missing cell of a matrix using the contents of *all* other cells. Anyone have ideas on how to do this?

**The context**: The matrix is *n* people's responses to *m* questions. Matrix shape is (n, m) with each cell ranging from -5 to +5. I want to gauge how "predictable" people's responses are, which I aim to do by

1. deleting the value of one cell
2. predicting that value using the rest of the matrix and recording the squared error
3. repeating this for all cells and averaging the error

**Idea**
I think using PCA (and not throwing away any dimensions) or correspondence analysis (?) is a good way to proceed, but I'm sketchy on the details.

Any ideas you have are much appreciated! Thanks.